# Remove leading digit from integer

Tags: swift, integer

I have an integer value, for example `-12345678`, and I want to remove
the leading digit, so that the result is `-2345678`.

One could convert it to string and remove 1 character, then remove 1 symbol.

Is there any simple way to achieve that?

Comment: make a loop saving in another variable the numbers from right to left, doing `%10` and `/10`, and don't save the last one. Don't know if there's a better way

Comment: Subtracting `10000000` from `12345678` will result in `2345678`. You could go that way, but your string solution is probably better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let value = -12345678
var text = "\(value)"

if text.hasPrefix("-") {
    let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    text.remove(at: index)
} else if text.characters.count > 1 {
    let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
    text.remove(at: index)
}
```

Output:

```
value = -12345678 will print out -2345678
value = 12345678 will print out 2345678
value = 0 will print out 0
```

Comment: Or: `if text.hasPrefix("-")`... – Minor nitpick: Zero would be transformed to an empty string.

Comment: @MartinR, I have updated the example. Much cleaner to use `hasPrefix`. I did also update to handle `0`. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution, using simple integer arithmetic:

```
func removeLeadingDigit(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    var m = n.magnitude
    var e = 1
    while m >= 10 {
        m /= 10
        e *= 10
    }
    return n - n.signum() * Int(m) * e
}
```

At the end of the loop, `m` is the leading digit of the given number
and `e` is the corresponding power of `10`, e.g. for `n = 432` we'll
get `m = 4` and `e = 100`. Some tests:

```
print(removeLeadingDigit(0))    // 0
print(removeLeadingDigit(1))    // 0
print(removeLeadingDigit(9))    // 0
print(removeLeadingDigit(10))   // 0
print(removeLeadingDigit(18))   // 8
print(removeLeadingDigit(12345))    // 2345

print(removeLeadingDigit(-12345))   // -2345
print(removeLeadingDigit(-1))       // 0
print(removeLeadingDigit(-12))      // -2

print(Int.max, removeLeadingDigit(Int.max)) // 9223372036854775807 223372036854775807
print(Int.min, removeLeadingDigit(Int.min)) // -9223372036854775808 -223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
let intValue = 12345678
let value = intValue % Int(NSDecimalNumber(decimal: pow(10, intValue.description.characters.count - 1)))
//value = 2345678
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let n = -123456
let m = n % Int(pow(10, floor(log10(Double(abs(n))))))
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319868/5536516

Comment: `n = 0` and `n = Int.min` lead to a crash (which may or may not be relevant)